# Automatically detect items which have an issue with multicollinearity

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(y=rnorm(500,0,20),x1=rnorm(500,50,100),x2=rnorm(500,10,40))
df$x3=df$x1+runif(500,-50,50); df$x4=df$x2+runif(500,-5,5)
```

This data contains multicollinear data. If I do this:

```
library(ppcor)
t <- pcor(df, method = "pearson")
t$estimate
```

I see that X1/X3 and X2/X4 have an issues with multicollinearity. Now I have to manually screen the output. Is there a way to detect these items automatically? And any thoughts on what should is the threshold?

Answer (score 0):

Regrading multicollinearity - there are many tests that can help you to detect multicollinearity. For example, you can calculate the "variance inflation factor" using the `vif` function in the `car` package.

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = df)
vifVues <- car::vif(fit)
```

In addition,  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Detection_of_multicollinearity) has a full page about detecting multicollinearity, and [this](https://datascienceplus.com/multicollinearity-in-r/) looks like a good blog post.

However, similar to what you did, I usually start with correlations in order to detect "problematic" high correlations. For that, you can try to "flatten" the correlation table and than to filter out high correlations.

Note: because I'm not familiar with `ppcor` I used `Hmisc`. However, the idea is the same.

```
require(tidyverse)
require(Hmisc)

#Flatten correlation matrix function
flattenCorrMatrix <- function (DF) 
{
  DF <- DF %>% as.matrix() %>% rcorr()
  ut <- upper.tri(DF$r)
  flat <- data.frame(row = rownames(DF$r)[row(DF$r)[ut]], column = rownames(DF$r)[col(DF$r)[ut]], 
                     cor = (DF$r)[ut], p = DF$P[ut], n = DF$n[ut])
  return(flat)
}

#using the function and filtering out the y variable and correlations higher than abs(0.7)
flattenCorrMatrix(df) %>% 
          filter(!grepl("y", row)) %>% 
          filter(cor > abs(0.7))
```

Output:

```
  row column       cor p   n
1  x1     x3 0.9626412 0 500
2  x2     x4 0.9972960 0 500
```